# Javascript Span as PHP Variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

As the title suggests, I have a span that is automatically generated by SimpleCart (Javascript Cart) - I want to use that span with a different checkout gateway then they support. Therefore, I need to take some of their  tags and "echo" them into PHP variables.

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fltAmount" value="###">

<span class="simpleCart_finalTotal">
```

The SPAN needs to be able to be passed into the INPUT so I can send it off to Paypoint.net

Comment: Thanks John. Cheap paste job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fltAmount" value="" id="fltAmount">
<span class="simpleCart_finalTotal" id="finalTotal">
```

And in the form, you will call a function (onsubmit) that looks like:

```
<form onSubmit="calledOnSubmit(event)" ... > ... </form>
```

An the function:

```
function calledOnSubmit(event) {
  var inputAmount = document.getElementById('fltAmount');
  var spanTag = document.getElementById('finalTotal');

  inputAmount.value = spanTag.innerHTML

}
```

Comment: Testing this out now. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Your code should not look like its from the 90's. Don't use JavaScript directly in your HTML.  Events should be attached unobtrusively, and behavior separated from structure.